# Is there a meta tag to support inertia scrolling

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

I currently have this set of code only for handling viewports.

`name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`

```
body {
     height: auto;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent using CSS or scripts to support scrolling on mobile devices?